# list to array without using array module in OCaml

Tags: arrays, list, function, ocaml

How can I convert list to an array without using array module?

```
let rec mk_hlp s v = 
  match s with 
  | 0 -> []
  | _ -> v :: mk_hlp (s-1) v;;

let mk s v = [|mk_hlp s v|];;
```

My attempt, but returns array of list.

Comment: I don't think you can. You need `Array.make` to create an array of arbitrary length at runtime... (Or `Array.of_list`, of course)

Comment: But in general to implement your own `Array.of_list`, you could first somehow create an array of the same length as the list, and then use `List.iteri` to populate it.

Comment: Yes, but my task is to implement module Array itself with functions, one of them is array.make :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, but it seems to me the assignment is probably to reproduce the *functionality* of arrays rather than to create arbitrary OCaml arrays without using functions in the `Array` module. This latter seems a fairly specious assignment (no offense to anybody involved). You're going to have to use *something* that creates an array (such as an array constant `[| ... |]`) and this for all practical purposes is really just another function in the `Array` module.

If instead you want to reproduce the *functionality* of arrays you can look for various other methods. It depends on what you *are* allowed to use. You can reproduce arrays at some level with just first-class functions and an `if` statement it seems to me.

Comment: Thank you for advice, that is what I'm doing now - trying to implement this functions with the help of the first-class functions. <3